# Vaadin "run later" func?

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to append some log strings to a `textArea` in my vaadin app.

```
VaadinSqlApplication.logger.info("Export start");
logTextArea.setValue("Export Start");
...
logTextArea.setValue("Export done");
```

but the `textArea` only changed after the whole function ended.
Is there any function like in JavaFX :

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //change text
            });
```

or in swing :

```
    EventQueue.invokeLater(changer);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable "push" on the Vaadin UI, as by default all updates to the UI will be grouped and sent as a single response (like you say: when the function returns).

Have a look at this page, it explains the whole setup very nicely:

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html

BTW, once push is enabled, you *will* need a similar technique as the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` that you mentioned:

> Making changes to a UI object from another thread and pushing them to
>   the browser requires locking the user session when accessing the UI.
>   Otherwise, the UI update done from another thread could conflict with
>   a regular event-driven update and cause either data corruption or
>   deadlocks. Because of this, you may only access an UI using the
>   access() method, which locks the session to prevent conflicts. It
>   takes a Runnable which it executes as its parameter.
>
> For example:

```
ui.access(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
});
```